# glob filenames | AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'

Tags: python-3.x, string, glob, attributeerror

I am running my own version of this [Notebook](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack/blob/master/tutorials/Tutorial16_Document_Classifier_at_Index_Time.ipynb), where section **Apply DocumentClassifier** is altered as below.

Objects `doc` in `documents` is `str` dtype. I assume it shoudln't be. **What dtype should `doc` be?**

**Jupyter Labs**, kernel: `conda_mxnet_latest_p37`.

**Cells:**

```
import glob
docs_to_classify = glob.glob('full-set-of-gri-standards-2021-english/*.pdf')
```

```
with open('filt_gri.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    tags = [current_place.rstrip() for current_place in filehandle.readlines()]

doc_classifier = TransformersDocumentClassifier(model_name_or_path="cross-encoder/nli-distilroberta-base",
                                                task="zero-shot-classification",
                                                labels=tags,
                                                batch_size=16)

classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)

all_docs = convert_files_to_dicts(dir_path=doc_dir)

preprocessor_sliding_window = PreProcessor(split_overlap=3,
                                           split_length=10,
                                           split_respect_sentence_boundary=False,
                                           split_by='passage')
```

**Output:**

```
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Using devices: CUDA
INFO - haystack.modeling.utils -  Number of GPUs: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-75f29230cd0e> in <module>
      7                                                 batch_size=16)
      8 
----> 9 classified_docs = doc_classifier.predict(docs_to_classify)
     10 
     11 all_docs = convert_files_to_dicts(dir_path=doc_dir)

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in predict(self, documents)
    134         :return: List of Document enriched with meta information
    135         """
--> 136         texts = [doc.content if self.classification_field is None else doc.meta[self.classification_field] for doc in documents]
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':

~/anaconda3/envs/mxnet_latest_p37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/haystack/nodes/document_classifier/transformers.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    134         :return: List of Document enriched with meta information
    135         """
--> 136         texts = [doc.content if self.classification_field is None else doc.meta[self.classification_field] for doc in documents]
    137         batches = self.get_batches(texts, batch_size=self.batch_size)
    138         if self.task == 'zero-shot-classification':

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add to post/ clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to include line, before `classified_docs`:

```py
# convert to Document using a fieldmap for custom content fields the classification should run on
docs_to_classify = [Document.from_dict(d) for d in docs_sliding_window]
```